# New Google Maps Symbol object in Marker makes IE really slow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I'm testing the new Symbols object of the Google Maps V3 API. I have set every "icon" attribute of 400 markers with the same Symbol path and color.

When look at the sample page with Firefox or Chrome, everything loads fast and works great.

Unfortunately... the performance in Internet Explorer are really bad. Bad at loading time and also when I try to drag or zoom on the map.

Here is a simple javascript example which you can use to test on IE

```
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);

  }

  function addMarkers() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                                          southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        icon:{  
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            scale: 4
         },
       map: map
      });
    }
  }
```

When you use it with some extra attributes and events it gets worst! But if you just delete the "icon" attribute of the marker, the basic Google marker appear and everything goes as fast as Chrome and Firefox...

Does anybody have an answer why this is that slow on IE when using Symbol and how can I speed up the process.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Internet Explorer version are you talking about?

Comment: @j0nes - I'm using IE 9 (9.0.8112.16421 - upgrade version 9.0.7 ) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol icons on Google Maps are part of the new [VectorIcons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#VectorIcons). These are no bitmaps, but are described as vector paths in SVG format. These are basically paths with a lot of points that get drawn until the shape is completed.

Now you have a lot of icons, which means a lot of SVG paths that have to be drawn. When you see different rendering speeds in different browsers, you are basically comparing the SVG rendering engines of the browsers - and from your application it looks like IE9 is slower than the other browsers.

I don't think there is a method to speed this up. You could either reduce the number of shown markers (for example with clustering) until you get to an acceptable rendering speed. Or you could simply use the Bitmap icons.

Comment: Thank you for your time, It makes sense but I test further yesterday with different IE version (using the IE developer tools) and it seems that the problem is only with IE9. IE8 and 7 are ok...  It seems that there is a problem with the IE9 javascript engine.

Comment: IE9 has a native SVG support, all older versions use a helper library [like outlined here](http://googlecode.blogspot.de/2009/10/svg-at-google-and-in-internet-explorer.html) or use other ways to draw vector data, for example in VML like in [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). This explains the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Well, I hope that they will rapidly improve their libraries... It is quite disappointing to see that a "modern" browser restrict the uses of a feature like Google Maps Symbol...

Comment: For 500 markers using a built-in google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE path, IE10 performance seem fine. IE9 comes to slow crawl and takes several minutes to render. IE8 is also too slow. IE7 hangs and never returns.